# Mistake in like SQL Server with Arabic language

Tags: sql-server

There is a database and in it a data table contains lots of values in Arabic language. When I use `like`, I get a wrong answer.

Code that I used

```
Select * 
From customers 
Where cusname like ''%جديد%
```

But kindly note the data already contains the values

Comment: you should write `'%جديد%'` not ''%جديد%

Comment: I tried it but still mistake

Comment: we cant help you without showing us your code. please read "How do I ask a good question": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Select * from customer where cusname like '%جديد٪'

Answer (score 4):

Use the Unicode prefix (N)

```
Select * from customer where cusname like N'%جديد٪'
```